# Transfer a Maven dependency + all transitive + parent POM

Tags: java, maven, gradle, repository, dependency-management

My project stores its dependencies in a Maven repository. I would like to be able to move certain dependencies to another Maven repository. The move is the easy part. But it's *what* to move that is difficult for me to get right.

In order for build tools such as Maven or Gradle to be able to use the moved dependency in a build, I need to also transfer (1) transitive dependencies (recursively) and (2) the project's parent POM file, performing (1) again on the parent until all nodes in the dependency graph are exhausted.

This seems like a very common usecase and I'm hedging my bets on the fact it has been implemented many times over.

**Question**: Are there common libraries that implement this functionality out-of-the-box?

If not, I'll probably have to implement a custom POM parser. Are my assumptions above about what needs to move correct?

Answer (score 2):

The [`copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin` may help you on this task:

> Goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a defined location.

It also provides an option, [`addParentPoms`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#addParentPoms) to also copy the parent poms required by the build (hence, the whole hierarchy). This option is not enabled by default though.

Moreover, via the different `include`/`exclude` options (by group Id, by artifact Id and so on) you may filter what you actually need to move.

Via its [`excludeTransitive`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeTransitive) option you may also check whether transitive dependencies are required or not: by default is set to `false`, hence transitive dependencies will be copied too.

Via its [`outputDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory) option you can specify where to copy dependencies, transitive dependencies and hierarchy of pom files, according to any specified filter.

---

You may also be interested in the combination of the [`purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin`, to delete from your local repository whatever required by the project (including transitive dependencies, hierarchy of pom, plugin dependencies) and the [`go-offline`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) goal to prepare the project for off-line mode, that is, to resolve (download) whatever required. Again, both goals provide include/exclude mechanisms and transitive dependencies management so that you may refine your strategy and outcome.

Answer (score 1):

`mvn dependency:list` will give you list of all dependencies of your project, including transitive dependencies and dependencies specified in your parent pom.

Comment: I'm not looking for all dependencies of the project, but transitive dependencies for a single given dependency. I also need the parent POM, not just the dependencies from it, as the build process will attempt to read the parent POM so I need to make sure it's moved too.

Comment: I guess you could download the dependency's pom into a directory then run the command there to see dependencies for that one dependency. I'm not sure whether parent poms do appear on that list or not, you'd have to check yourself.